# Should I add 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0' to build.gradle when I need to use Google in-app?

Tags: android-studio, in-app

I use Kotlin and Android Studio 3.0, in order to use AdMob Ad, I should add   `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'` to build.gradle.

Now I hope to use Google in-app, should Ito add   `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0' to build.gradle` ?

BTW, does it `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0` include all Google services ? and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0` only for AD?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only AdMob, 
you should use individual API **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'**

For [More information](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: Thanks! If I need to use in-app, do I need to add com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0?

Comment: If you use only AdMob, add implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'. 

No need to use implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'.

Comment: Now, I need to use in-app, do I need to add com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0?